# SQL Server remote connection problem

Tags: c#, sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2005, and crated one user.

I am able to connect from the same systen, but while connecting from other system on the LAN it showing the error like below

> login failed for the user xxxx. The user is not associated with a trusted sql server connection.

I googled the issue but nothing is sorted out for me. Even some posts on StackOverflow, where it mention to use SQL Server and Windows Authentication also didn't help.

Comment: How you configured the Authentication? Mixed Mode or only SQL Sever Auth ? For some help take a look a this KB : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889615

Comment: @JNK : It's all wrong... Trusted sql server connection means that it's not a user of sql server... have nothing to do with illegal copy!

Comment: Is the server in a domain or a workgroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is an extra step you have to accomplish... Try to enable the TCP/IP trasport on the Configuration in SQL Server Surface Area Configuration.

This link can help you :

[Configure MS SQL Server 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_Server_2005_remote.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set SQL Server and Windows authentication mode in server property. Enterprise Manager -> Right click on the server -> Properties -> tab Security -> Authentication: SQL Server and Windows authentication instead Windows Authentication mode

Comment: The setting is already set to mixed mode (SQL Server and Windows Authentication) but no luck